# Elementary OS 4 Loki Black Screen on Boot/Login After Updates

Tags: updates, boot, nvidia, uefi, secure-boot

the other day I decided to run some updates to software and the OS from the App Center and it broke my system somehow.

The only odd thing I noticed regarding the updates before it crashed was that a prompt to add a password to UEFI Secure Boot popped up which I closed out of without entering one.

It seems to me the updates froze during install and the system froze and crashed. After that, I could not get back in. The OS seems to boot, but it boots to a blank (black) login screen. When I enter my password, it looks as if it will work and then goes back to the login screen.

I have tried to set: "nomodeset" to the grub but am unsure if I did it right. I really don't want to reinstall the OS because it was so stable before and I have a ton of data saved to it.

System Specs:
MSI GS63 
i7-6700hq
Nvidia GTX 1060
16 GB Ram
128 SSD+ 1tb hdd

Here are an example of the error messages I received when digging into recovery mode/ different kernels, etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Making matters worse, I cannot boot into elementary via a live usb. It freezes after clicking "try before installing" after flashing something about a "firmware error" that is too fast to read. Windows is working fine however. I am at a loss, please help.

Comment: Edit: the boot drive worked finally for some reason but i cannot access my files from the elementary install.

Comment: Although I got in once, it has proved an aberration. I cannot get in via a live usb at all. Elementary just hangs on the splash screen forever. Windows works fine.